# Accessing NIFI UI remotely

Tags: installation, apache-nifi

I did install Nifi on Linux, updated the nifi properties

```
nifi.web.https.host='ip address where nifi is running'
nifi.web.https.port=8443
```

Yet when i try to launch browser

```
https://ip:8443/nifi
```

i am unable to launch the Nifi UI. Kindly let me know if anything else has to be set in the NIFI properties to access the UI remotely

Comment: Check that nifi is running. Try `curl --insecure https://ip:8443/nifi` on local and on remote. What error do you see? Check the port allowed in firewall on Linux or temporarily disable firewall.

Comment: i am getting the same error on  both local and remote  "curl:(7) failed connect to ip:8443;Connection refused . But when i do ps -ef| i do see the nif.sh start still running along with process for bootstrap. Also the port is open

Comment: check nifi logs. do you have errors in it?

Comment: no errors i find in the logs

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is check that the NiFi service/process is running properly. If the NiFi service isnt running properly, then getting it to run will help solve the issues. However, if it is running, I would check that the port is open using a command such as netstat -an | grep 8443 to show what is listening on that port. You can then connect to whatever the netstat command shows. Also check the nifi.properties file to confirm that the information being used is properly set and configured.